# Trying to remove value from class

Tags: c#, class, integer

I've been trying to remove manually entered value from 'Solmu' class after changing it to integer.

```
 private static void PoiataTiettyArvo(ref Solmu lista)
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Anna arvo jonka haluat poistaa: ");
     int PoistaMinut = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

     int arvo = Convert.ToInt32(lista.data);

     if(PoistaMinut != null)
     {
         arvo.RemoveAt(PoistaMinut);
     }
 }
```

My Solmu class is defined like this:

```
public class Solmu
{
    public Solmu next;
    public Solmu prev;
    public double data;
}
```

Seems RemoveAt does not work with this, any alternatives?

Comment: What is the `Solmu` class?

Comment: I would like to remove PoistaMinut from lista.data < which is double 
class Solmu
        {
            public Solmu next;
            public Solmu prev;

            public double data;
        }

Comment: For future readers: `Anna arvo jonka haluat poistaa:` translates (in Google) to `Enter the value you want to delete:`.

Comment: You should post that class; A linked list basically? No methods? You'll have to manually traverse the list to remove if you don't already have your own method.

Comment: yes it is linked list, could you please tell more about what should I do to get the value remove without sabataging the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Okay, now I understand what you're trying to do. You're going through a linked list to remove an item that matches the item that the user enters.

Option 1) If your `Solmu` class has an implementation of `RemoveAt`, you can call it as I posted below - however, `RemoveAt` methods typically expect an index value, so I would call it `Remove` (or something more specific like `RemoveValue`).

Option 2) If your `Solmu` class is self-created, you will need a loop that starts with the head value and compares the `data` field to the user-entered value, and remove it.

(Removed my code in favor of Jacob's.)

---

**Original answer:**

You're not removing anything from `lista`. Your code:

```
int PoistaMinut = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int arvo = Convert.ToInt32(lista.data);
if(PoistaMinut != null)
{
   arvo.RemoveAt(PoistaMinut); // <- Remove an int from an int?
}
```

is trying to remove something from `arvo`.

You should modify your code to say

```
lista.RemoveAt(PoistaMinut);
```

instead.

(In that case, however, I wonder what purpose `arvo` serves. Can you elaborate?)

Comment: lista.data content is double, I'm trying to convert it to Int. Therefore I've used this line int arvo = Convert.ToInt32(lista.data);

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. It worked.
Regarding your question Why I'm using double to store int's. This is according to our homework instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, this looks like a linked list. You'll have to loop through your values to find the *node* to delete (this code is untested):

```
private static void PoiataTiettyArvo(ref Solmu lista)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Anna arvo jonka haluat poistaa: ");
    int PoistaMinut = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var previousNode = null;
    var currentNode = lista;
    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        int arvo = Convert.ToInt32(lista.data);
        if (PoistaMinut == arvo)
        {
            if (previousNode == null)
            {
                // If there was no previous node, the head of the list is being deleted.
                // update lista
                lista = currentNode;
            }
            else
            {
                previousNode.next = currentNode.next;
                if (currentNode.next != null)
                {
                    currentNode.next.prev = previousNode;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        previousNode = currentNode;
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob very much for your help. However, I've tried your code and it didn't work. Also, I've tried to change few things as Visual studio suggested and still stuck. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @CsharpNewbie - for best results, tell us the errors you get.

Comment: First error was: Cannot assign <null> to an implicitly-typed local variable in var PreviousNode = null so I've changed it to Solmu PreviousNode = null and the error disappeared. However, when I try to remove the value the code does nothing.. I still get the same values.